# Why does this vlookup result in an error message

Tags: vba

When I try to run the code below, the following error message pops up: "Unable to get the Vlookup property of the WorksheetFunction class"

I stepped through the code and this pops up on the second vlookup. The first vlookup runs fine.

The only differences between the two lookups are that the value being searched for has changed from Range("R" & i) -> Range("S" & rrow); i and rrow are both integers and both ranges have values that exist.

```
Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, 22) = Not(IsError(Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Range("R" & i),Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("AD:AD"), 1, False)))

Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, 21) = Not(IsError(Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Range("S" & rrow),Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("AD:AD"), 1, False)))
```

If anyone can inform me as to why this occurs, it will be a great help!

---

Comment: `Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup` will stop the code if a match is not found.  `Not(IsError(` will never trap the error.  remove the `.WorksheetFunction` part. and it will pass the error.

Answer (score 1):

The `WorksheetFuntion` interface is early-bound: at design-time you get auto-completion, parameter quick-info tooltips, etc. At run-time, early-bound `WorksheetFunction` will *raise* actual VBA runtime errors if it fails.

So the return value never even gets to `IsError`, because the error isn't *returned*, but *raised*.

As [Scott mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55423582/why-does-this-vlookup-result-in-an-error-message#comment97566237_55423582), you can use `Application.VLookup` instead - that's late-bound, so at design-time you get no auto-completion, no parameter quick-info tooltips; the compiler won't help you if you make a typo. At run-time, late-bound worksheet functions will *return* error values (an actual `Variant/Error` value), which can be compared against e.g. `CVErr(xlErrNA)`, or fed to `IsError` to be evaluated.

`Not IsError(expression)` will return a Boolean value, not the lookup value - this may or may not be what you intended.

So, replace `Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup` with `Application.VLookup`, and your code should work... except...

> *and both ranges have values that exist*

If that were the case, the early-bound `WorksheetFunction.VLookup` wouldn't be raising an error (assuming your parameters are all correct).

Lastly, since you're only interested in whether the value exists or not, consider using `Application.Match` (`WorksheetFunction.Match`) instead - it also returns an `#N/A` error value if the lookup value isn't found, but *should* perform a bit better.

"Unable to get the {function name} property of the WorksheetFunction class" could also mean that your parameters are wrong in some way. Row numbers should be `Long`, not `Integer`, and note that `Range("R" & i)` is implicitly referring to whatever the `ActiveSheet` is, since it's not qualified with a proper `Worksheet` object reference - maybe the active sheet isn't the one your code assumes?